# Convert WrappedArray into Dataframe Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-avro

I have the structure of the avro File like the one given below and I would like to convert  the WrappedArray values into specific columns:

```
root
 |-- reportId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- row: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- fieldRec: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)

 

  //Reading and selecting specific column from Avro
  val empDF = spark.read.format("avro").load("/PRD/DRV/EMP_DETAILS/fact_date=20220404")
                    .select("col.fieldRec.value")
 //I have selected now the "value" which is having WrappedArray
 empDF.show()
```

The result looks like:

```
+------------------------------------+
| value                              |
+------------------------------------+
|WrappedArray(EmployeeId,Name,salary)|
|WrappedArray(100,James,300000)      |
|WrappedArray(101,John,400000)       |
|WrappedArray(102,Fern,350000)       |
|WrappedArray(103,Philip,310000)     |
+------------------------------------+
```

Now, I am changing the WrappedArray values getting populated in each columns:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

//Defining Case Class
case class Employee(employeeId: String, name: String, salary: String)

//Reading and selecting specific column from DataFrame
val empDF = spark.read.format("avro").load("/PRD/DRV/EMP_DETAILS/fact_date=20220404")
                .select("col.fieldRec.value")

//Select the First record from the DataFrame                
val firstRec = empDF.first 

//Filtering out the first record
val empDFMinus = empDF.filter(row => row != firstRec)

//Identifying the size of the Array which could be used at the later stage
val arrayLength = empDF.select(size(col("value"))).first.get(0).toString.toInt - 1

import spark.implicits._

//Converting WrappedArray to a structure which I would like to represent
val empDFCols = empDFMinus.as[ArrayBuffer[String]].map(arr => Employee(arr(0),arr(1),arr(2)))

empDFCols.printSchema()

empDFCols.show()

root
 |-- employeeId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary  : string (nullable = true)
 
+----------------------------+ 
|employeeId | name | salary  |
+----------------------------+
|100        |James | 300000  |
|101        |John  | 400000  |
|102        |Fern  | 350000  |
|103        |Philip| 310000  |
+----------------------------+
```

***Could you please let me know of any other better way to do this, please?***

Comment: Did import spark.implicits._; empDF.as[Employee] not work?

Comment: Hi @Chris, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it. But, it didn't work. It is throwing me error as below:                                                     
           org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`employeeId`' given input columns: [value];

Comment: can you please attach your sample avro file ?

Comment: @VijayB got you, try adding after your select.. .selectExpr("element_at(value,1) employeeId","element_at(value,2) name","element_at(value,3) salary").as[Employee]

Comment: Hi @Chris, This works perfectly fine now. But, I have 109 values in the WrappedArray, should I then give something like val empDFCols = empDFMinus.selectExpr("element_at(value,1) employeeId","element_at(value,2) name", "element_at(value,3) salary", "element_at(value,4) designation"..........."element_at(value,109).as[Employee] which is similar to the code I have tried val empDFCols = empDFMinus.as[ArrayBuffer[String]].map(arr => Employee(arr(0),arr(1),arr(2)))

Comment: Do you think, I can simply increment the column names dynamically using for loop as col1,col2,col3.....col109 and then convert it using case class. val empDFCols = empDFMinus.as[ArrayBuffer[String]].map(arr => Employee( for(i <- 0 to colsCnt) var res += arr($i)+",")) Anything like this possible?

Comment: Hi @Srinivas, Sorry, I would not be able to upload this file from my office environment.

Comment: 109 attributes isn't a great domain model, use the same approach but break them up into different classes where each class is a struct.  If you truly need dynamic then there is nothing "wrong" with what you had before